# Jhipster : issue with mvn package

Tags: node.js, jhipster

I have to maintain a jhipster v3.0 web app.
I know that this version is not supported anymore but maybe some of you have faced this issue and will be able to help me.

I have installed Node, NPM, Yo, Bower and GULP.

When I run `mvn -Pprod package -Dmaven.test.skip=true` on my webapp, I am getting this error :

```
[INFO] node version :
v8.10.0
[INFO] npm version :
5.6.0
[INFO] --------------------------------------
[INFO]          NPM INSTALL
[INFO] --------------------------------------
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 5.803s
[INFO] bower version :
1.8.2
[INFO] --------------------------------------
[INFO]          BOWER INSTALL --NO-COLOR
[INFO] --------------------------------------
bower                     invalid-meta for:/home/myapp/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/bower.json
bower                     invalid-meta The "name" is recommended to be lowercase, can contain digits, dots, dashes
bower angular-cookies extra-resolution Unnecessary resolution: angular-cookies#1.5.2
[INFO] gulp version :
[14:17:21] CLI version 3.9.1
[14:17:21] Local version 3.9.1
[INFO] --------------------------------------
[INFO]          GULP TEST --NO-COLOR
[INFO] --------------------------------------
[14:17:22] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/gulpfile.js
[14:17:22] Starting 'wiredep:test'...
[14:17:22] Starting 'ngconstant:dev'...
[14:17:22] 'ngconstant:dev' errored after 29 ms
[14:17:22] Error in plugin 'gulp-tslint-log'
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received null
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:1349:5)
    at getFilePath (/home/myapp/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:95:27)
    at DestroyableTransform.objectStream [as _transform] (/home/myapp/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:60:25)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/home/myapp/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/home/myapp/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (/home/myapp/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (/home/myapp/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/home/myapp/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.end (/home/myapp/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:352:10)
    at ngConstantPlugin (/home/myapp/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:33:16)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/myapp/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/gulpfile.js:164:12)
    at module.exports (/home/myapp/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/myapp/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/myapp/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/home/myapp/Documents/workspaces/aprhmyapp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a version of node that is too recent: v8.10.0.

At the time of JHipster 3, it was probably node 4.x, try downgrading and consider using a node environment manager to easily switch between versions.

In addition, consider editing your `pom.xml` to replace yeoman-maven-plugin by frontend-maven-plugin which enables you to specify versions of node and related tools (npm, bower, gulp) to isolate your prod builds from your dev environment. This is what JHipster 4 uses.

Comment: I needed node 4.x to package the app. node 6 led to the same issue.

Comment: That s good to know! thanks. Wish I had time and money to start over this project from scratch with jhipster 4 though :)